# putObject makes object larger on server in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor

I'm using Nodejs to try and push an image to an S3 instance with the aws-sdk.  Currently, it reads from a file on the client and then saves it on the server (I'm using a meteor framework.)  I'd like to push it to the S3 server instead of saving it on the meteor server.  When I tried to migrate it over, the images seem to gain about 30% when they are on S3.  If I try and download them off of S3 the image is no longer viewable either, so it looks like it has changed encoding or something.

Here is the code to load the file on the client side:

```
saveFile = function( blob, name, path, type, callback ) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  var method;
  var encoding = 'binary';
  var type = type || 'binary';

  switch( type ) {
    case 'text':
      method = 'readAsText';
      encoding = 'utf8';
      break;
    case 'binary':
      method = 'readAsBinaryString';
      encoding = 'binary';
      break;
    default:
      method = 'readAsBinaryString';
      encoding = 'binary';
      break;   
  }

  // Call the save function on the server after the file has been read.
  fileReader.onload = function( file ) {
    console.log( "File loaded..." );
    Meteor.call( 'saveFile', file.srcElement.result, name, path, encoding, callback );
  }

  // Read the file
  fileReader[ method ]( blob );
}
```

On the server side:

```
  saveFile: function( file, name, path, encoding ) {
    s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
      var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, ContentType: 'binary', ContentEncoding: 'utf8', Body: file};
      s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err)
        else
          console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
      });
    });
```

Comment: looks like your base64 encoding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution, it was to encapsulate the 'file' object in a

```
new Buffer()
```

Simple, but oh so difficult to find!!