# How can I upload a file from an HTTP response body to S3 using putObject() from the AWS SDK (in Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to save a PDF file into S3 with the AWS SDK.
I'm getting the PDF through the body of a POST request (`Application/PDF`).

When saving the file into the local HD with `fs.writeFile`, the file looks ok. But when uploading it to S3, the file is corrupted (it's just a single 
 page PDF).

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var data = body // body from a POST request.
var fileName = "test.pdf";

fs.writeFile(fileName, data, {encoding : "binary"}, function(err, data) {
    console.log('saved'); // File is OK!
});

s3.putObject({ Bucket: "bucketName", Key: fileName, Body: data }, function(err, data) {
    console.log('uploaded') // File uploads incorrectly.
});
```

EDIT:

It works if I write and then read the file and then upload it.

```js
fs.writeFile(fileName, data, {encoding : "binary"}, function(err, data) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, fileData) {
        s3.putObject({ Bucket: "bucketName", Key: fileName, Body: fileData }, function(err, data) {
            console.log('uploaded') // File uploads correctly.
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the contentType and/or ContentEncoding on your put to S3.

```
 ContentType: 'binary', ContentEncoding: 'utf8'
```

See the code sample here for working example [putObject makes object larger on server in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056525/putobject-makes-object-larger-on-server-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because the data is consumed (i.e. a stream).

It would explain why after writting the data you send nothing to S3 and reading again the data  you can send a valid PDF.

Try and see if it works by just sending the data directly to S3 without writting it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you forgot about callback of writeFile function, so when you started uploading to Amazon S3 your file wasn't saved completly. You shouldn't forget that node.js is asynchronous and an app won't wait when the `fs.writeFile` finishes it work, it simply run `s3.putObject` the same time.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. I was uploading and saving in parallel just to show that the data was not corrupted. BTW the complete data is available in "var data"

Comment: Missed it. Then, I think, something wrong was with encoding (ContentEncoding and ContentType in params) as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

/**
* JS library: Promise.promisify from bluebirdjs
**/

My code is as below

```
global.Promise = require('bluebird');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const aswAccessKey = {
    accessKeyId: 'your-accesskey-id',
    secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-access-key'
};
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');

// Create S3 service object
// available apiVersion: '2006-03-01', '2013-04-01',
const s3 = new aws.S3(Object.assign(aswAccessKey, {
    apiVersion: '2013-04-01'
}));

function putObject(bucketName, file) {
    console.log('putObject into ', bucketName);
    /**
     * If we don't use versioned bucket, we must not pass VersionId
     */
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: '',
        Body: 'Plain text',
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: 'binary',
        CacheControl: 'max-age=172800'
    };

    return Promise
        .promisify(fs.readFile, {
            context: fs
        })(file)
        .then((fileData) => {
            console.log(fileData);
            params.Body = fileData;
            params.Key = 'g01/' + uuidV4() + '-' + path.basename(file);
            return Promise
                .promisify(s3.putObject, {
                    context: s3
                })(params)
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('successful');
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Error', err);
                });
        })
        .catch(() => {
        });
}
```

Comment: we don't want to see the code, try to give relevent explanation which will help in understanding it.